# Проблема с циклом. Функции С++

Tags: c++, функции, циклы

Даны массивы a(3,4), b(2,5). Найти Z = (Ma+Mb)/(da+db), где Ma ,Mb - среднеарифметические значения массивов A, B. da, db - максимальные отклонения от среднеарифметических значений.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Print_arrays_A_B(float* arrA, float* arrB)//вывод массивов A и B на экран.
{
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Array A:" << arrA[i]<<endl;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        cout <<"Array B:"<< arrB[i]<<endl;
    }
}
float Mean_arrays_A_B(float* arrA, float *arrB)//вычисление среднеарифметического массивов
{
    float SA=0;
    float SB=0;
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        SA=SA+arrA[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        SB=SA+arrB[i];
    }
    SA=SA/2;
    SB=SB/2;
    return SA;
    return SB;
}
float Dev_Mean(float* arrA, float* arrB, float* Ma_arrA, float* Mb_arrB)
{
  const int sizedev_arr=2;
  float dev_arrA[sizedev_arr];
  for (int i=0; i<2; i++ ) 
  {
      dev_arrA[i]=arrA[i]-Ma_arrA;
  }
}

int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
 float Ma_arrA;//Переменная среднеарифметического массива A
 float Mb_arrB;//Переменная среднеарифметического массива B
 float arrA[2]={3, 4};//массив А
 float arrB[2]={2, 5};//массив B
 Print_arrays_A_B(arrA, arrB);//отправление массива A и B
 Mean_arrays_A_B(arrA, arrB);//отправление массива A и B
 Ma_arrA=Mean_arrays_A_B(arrA, arrB);//Присвоение значений, вычисленных в функции
 Mb_arrB=Mean_arrays_A_B(arrB, arrB);//Присвоение значений, вычисленных в функции
 Dev_Mean(arrA, arrB, Ma_arrA, Mb_arrB);
 cout <<"Среднеарифметическое массива А:"<< Ma_arrA<<endl;
 cout <<"Среднеарифметическое массива B:"<< Mb_arrB;
}
```

Проблема с функцией Dev_Mean, которая должна считать отклонение от среднеарифметического. Я решил считать его так. Создать массив и заполнить его элементами разницы массиваА-среднеарифметическое. Затем искать в этом массиве максимальный элемент(этот кусок еще не написан, тк у меня возникла проблема). Помогите пожалуйста, укажите на причину, по которой не работает присвоение элементов массиву dev_arrA.

Comment: а с чего вы решили что присваивание не работает?

Comment: Потому что вылезает ошибка:                                                                                                  main.cpp: In function ‘float Dev_Mean(float*, float*, float*, float*)’:
main.cpp:38:26: error: invalid operands of types ‘float’ and ‘float*’ to binary ‘operator-’
       dev_arrA[i]=arrA[i]-Ma_arrA;
                   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:53:39: error: cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘float Dev_Mean(float*, float*, float*, float*)’
  Dev_Mean(arrA, arrB, Ma_arrA, Mb_arrB);

Comment: ну так а почему вы не читаете ошибки, который вам выдает компилятор?

Comment: Честно говоря, я не очень понимаю, что говорит компилятор. Поэтому и обратился сюда.

Comment: ну вот что не понятного в в строке: "invalid operands of types ‘float’ and ‘float*’ to binary ‘operator-’"? Вам же компилятор напрямую пишет, что вы пытаетесь применить `-` к переменным типа `float` и `float*`. Если вам и это не понятно, то выучите сначала базовый синтаксис языка

Answer (score 1):

Разыменуйте указательную переменную

```
dev_arrA[i]=arrA[i]- *Ma_arrA;
```

Но вообще в данном случае, вероятно, нет смысла передавать аргумент по адресу, ведь он не меняется внутри функции.